# Changing color of plot when value is increasing

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to make plot that has two colors of line red and blue, and the line should be red when value is increasing and blue when value is decreasing and when I use dotted line it works 'b*' but without this it doesn't work 'b' I think I should define first point of plot but I'm not sure.

```
x = -10:.01:10;
for ii = 1:length(x)
      y(ii) = sin(x(ii));  % Data point ii has come in.
      if y(ii)<0
          c = 'b*';
      else
          c = 'r*';
      end
      plot(x(ii),y(ii),c)
      hold on
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to plot the chart as a "line" you have to pass at least 2 point to the plot function.

Also, in the question, you state that you want to distinguish, by color, between increasing and decreasing values, but in the code you have published you text whether the value is positive or negative.

In the first section of the code you can find a possible solution in which the color of the line discriminates between positive and negative values.
In the second, the color distinguishes between increasing and decreasing values.

```
x = -10:.01:10;
y = sin(x);  % Data point ii has come in.
for ii = 1:length(x)-1
      if y(ii)<0
          c = 'b';
      else
          c = 'r';
      end
      plot([x(ii) x(ii+1)],[y(ii) y(ii+1)],c)
      hold on
end
grid
```

[image]

```
x = -10:.01:10;
y = sin(x);  % Data point ii has come in.
for ii = 1:length(x)-1
      if (y(ii) > y(ii+1))
          c = 'b';
      else
          c = 'r';
      end
      plot([x(ii) x(ii+1)],[y(ii) y(ii+1)],c)
      hold on
end
grid
```

[image]